# How to use AirPrint to print a locked pdf file

Tags: ios, pdf, passwords, core-graphics

I know use `CGPDFDocumentUnlockWithPassword` to unlock a pdf, but it returned a `CGPDFDocumentRef`, and if I want use AirPrint to print it, it should be a `NSData` or a url, But I don't know how to convert a `CGPDFDocumentRef` to a `NSData` object or a save it as a file . Did anyone have a idea to solve this case?

Answer (score 0):

Simply printing each page of your source pdf into a newly created `CGPDFContext` and saving the resulting pdf to separate file should do it. Principially, it should look like this:

```
// create PDFContext
NSURL* dstPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathInCachesFolder]
CGRect pageRect = CGRectMake(0,0,1024,1024); // example, use real page size of src document here
CGContextRef pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL(dstPath, &pageRect, nil);

// use for loop here to repeat following stuff for each pdf page from the src pdf
CGPDFContextBeginPage(pdfContext, NULL);
CGContextDrawPDFPage(pdfContext, sourcePDFpageRef);
CGPDFContextEndPage(pdfContext);

// close pdfContext, saves dst file
CGPDFContextClose(pdfContext);
CGContextRelease (pdfContext);
```

This piece of code just prints a page from the source pdf to the newly created pdf and saves the pdf to the dst path. Of course, you'll have repeat the drawing part for each page from the source document. Afterwards you should be able to print the pdf via AirPrint without any problems.

Comment: thanks for your answer , but i don't want to redraw the pdf to context.I just want to save the CGPDFDocumentRef to disc or use it to print

Answer (score -2):

I already solved this question. you can have information here:

[How to pass a password to UIPrintInteractionController when using AirPrint to print a locked pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031929/how-to-pass-a-password-to-uiprintinteractioncontroller-when-using-airprint-to-pr)